# What are the amd64 files in Windows 7 x64?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

Is it safe to delete "amd64" files from my Windows folder?  My machine is a Dell using an Intel Processor, so why would I need AMD files?

If they are 'protected' how can I delete batches of them?

I am using Windows 7 x64 Ultimate

Comment: Your OS is using your Intel processor in AMD64 mode. It might be an Intel CPU, but the current 64 bit extentions come from AMD, hence their name. (Intel had other 64 bit plans, look up [Itanium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itanium) if you are curious about those.)

Comment: Zds is right, that they are Windows code, so don't remove them YOURSELF, but as Honest Guy Reno says, depending upon where they are... WELL... specifically, if they are in the WINSXS folder, microsoft is now giving you a utility to remove *SOME* of them:  do an internet search on ***"desktop experience winsxs"***, or check out this link:  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2014/05/13/how-to-clean-up-the-winsxs-directory-and-free-up-disk-space-on-windows-server-2008-r2-with-new-update/

Answer (score 23):

Do not. "AMD64" is the name for the 64-bit instruction set the x64 Windows *runs* on. It just happens to be AMD who invented the 64-bit x86 instruction set, which Intel copied later on.

Comment: (Similar to how Intel invented the 32-bit instruction set for x86, and AMD copied it later on.)

Comment: And **amd64** is just "small extension" to "complete" x86 architecture developed (from scratch?) by Intel.

Answer (score 1):

Where the directory resides is important.  You'll find files with these names in many locations.  If they subtend a directory containing some string of fairly meaningless hexidecimal symbols, e.g., 12c8b0aaa7c55472e285280a, the subtending files and directories are probably garbage left over from an installation routine that was sloppily written.

First rename the aforementioned top level directory and run your computer for a couple days. If nothing seems amiss, then you're fairly safe deleting them.  If they are locked, then you'll need to do some research on how to unlock them.