# Huge amount of "amd64_" files in winsxs 8.93GB, what are they?

Tags: windows-7

I have a huge amount of folders under my "C:/Windows/winsxs" folder that all start with amd64_. They have sub headings ranging from "wpf" to "security" even to "netflix". The entire size of the files is 8.93.GB. What are theses? What created them? Can I delete them all?

[image]

Comment: this may help http://superuser.com/questions/331656/what-are-the-amd64-files-in-windows-7-x64

Comment: I guess, but I am not sure if they are the same. I need something more concrete before I leave them there.

Comment: There are many explanations of what's in the WinSXS folder. [Here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2008/09/17/what-is-the-winsxs-directory-in-windows-2008-and-windows-vista-and-why-is-it-so-large.aspx) is one from Microsoft.

Comment: To sum up some very wise advice from Micrsoft.  The WinSxS folder is there to make sure your system is stable, if your system ever has integrity issues, you will want that folder @100%

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AMD64` is the codename for the 64Bit Version of Windows because AMD created the first [64Bit architecture with their AMD K8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD64#History_of_AMD64) (Athlon64/Opteron) which was still compatible to the existing 32Bit Windows.

So all AMD64 files you see are 64Bit files. No you can't delete them. You can [only safely cleanup WinSxS](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2013/10/08/breaking-news-reduce-the-size-of-the-winsxs-directory-and-free-up-disk-space-with-a-new-update-for-windows-7-sp1-clients.aspx) by running disk cleanup after [installing Update KB2852386](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2852386/en-us) to remove Updates which are replaced by newer ones.

Comment: i tried from the command line, from disk cleanup.. it all says it is clean but the folder is 8GB! what can I do now? win11

Comment: @Mikey you can't do anything if you already called the cleanup via disk cleanup or DISM

Comment: it was a bit suspicious that the DSIM went to 20% quickly then stopped.. no 100% and said it was finished.. but no errors

Comment: @Mikey look in CBS.log/DISM.log for errors